# Why "accept" an answer?

Tags: discussion

What exactly is the point of accepting an answer? Once all the answers are up, its a bit meaningless to say that you accept one particular answer. Perhaps the only reason to have an accept button is to close the question and put it in a "resolved" category. Is this its purpose?

(I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the whole dynamics behind this. Perhaps the person whose answer is accepted gets his/her reputation bumped-up? Etc..)

Comment: Highest upvoted answer!=best answer. I've seen quite a few times (not too much on physics.SE) where there's a well written, highly upvoted answer that does not fully answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

The intent of this feature is that you accept the answer which actually solves your problem. This originated on Stack Overflow, and it makes sense there because for programming questions, it's easy for the original poster to try out various solutions and unambiguously determine which one actually works. For physics questions, on the other hand, the OP may not be in a position to judge which answer (if any) is correct, so accepting doesn't always make quite as much sense for this site.

Still, it does offer a way to show that you've gotten a satisfactory answer, and so accepting an answer can be thought of as a way to mark a question as "resolved." It's not resolved in the sense you might see the term elsewhere, though - if a question has an accepted answer, that shouldn't discourage you from posting your own answer if you think it adds value. Questions with accepted answers should certainly **not** be considered "closed" in any sense.

When you accept an answer to your question, the person who posted the answer gets 15 reputation, and you get 2 reputation. This is meant to encourage people to accept answers to their questions.

For more details, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: In addition, it offers a way for a brand new user--[not yet able to upvote](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)--to reward and indicate a good answer.